# Losing data on a Pandas DataFrame reindex

Tags: python, pandas

I was losing data on a reindex.  I just wanted to make an existing column the index.

So this works:

```
df_all_maa = df_all_maa.set_index("VERSION_SEQ")
```

Originally I was doing this:

```
df_all_maa = df_all_maa.reindex(df_all_maa["VERSION_SEQ"])
```

I think what was happening was I was only getting values in the resulting dataframe, where the VERSION_SEQ value happened to match the numeric default index, but I would be interested to know what my original incorrect syntax was actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

`reindex` is similar to `loc`, but allowing non-existing indexes. `reindex` creates a row with `nan` values whence there are non-existing indexes, while `loc` would throw an error.

Comment: thanks for this. I was trying to understand what my statement was actually asking Pandas to do?